# the easiest way to get number from string

Tags: c#

i want to retrive some number from string, for example "valueID = 234232" or "valueID = 2" or "valueID=23" or "valueID= 2" or "valueID =234", so what is the easiest way to get this number assuming that after this number is space " " or end of line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string input = "valueID = 234232";
var split = input.Split(new char[] {'='});
int value = int.Parse(split[1].Trim());
```

Comment: is this slower of faster then regex?

Comment: Regex is generally slower than using bare string manipulation functions.

Comment: the shouldn't differ noticeably in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your sure there will be a number in there

```
int.parse( Regex.match(String, @"\d+").value)
```

Comment: And hope it's not something like `value3 = 27`

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regex:

```
  Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+");
  if (match.Success) 
  {
     number = int.Parse(match.Value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some flexible code I use all the time for this sort of thing:

```
public const string FilterDigits = "0123456789";
public const string FilterLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

/// <summary>
/// Strips away any characters not defined in validChars and returns the result.
/// </summary>
public static string FilterTo(string text, string validChars)
{
StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i <= text.Length; i++) {
    char CurrentChar = Convert.ToChar(Strings.Mid(text, i, 1));

    if (validChars.Contains(CurrentChar)) {
        Result.Append(CurrentChar);
    }
}

return Result.ToString;
}
```

Then you can just call:

```
 int.parse(FilterTo("valueID=23", FilterDigits));
```

It could also be turned into a handy extension method, then you could do:

```
 int.parse("valueID=23".FilterTo(FilterDigits));
```

Comment: didn't u check tags? to be honest, only one, "C#"

Comment: @kosnkov: It's all .net to me :) I converted it, should be more suitable now.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've parsed out your potential number (through regex, split, substr, etc), TryParse is a great improvement (since .NET 3.5 at least):

```
string myPotentialNumber = "1";
int myNumber;
bool isNumber = int.TryParse(myPotentialNumber, out myNumber);

if( isNumber )
{
   //do something
}
else
{
   //throw error
}
```

TryParse() is exception safe, which makes it a bit faster and cleaner for many types of conversions.